# How to display the connected component through a specific pixel coordinate

Tags: matlab, image-processing, grayscale, connected-components

I have a gray scale image `add1`, however there are only two pixel intensities in it (0 for Black and 255 for White). I am able to track the coordinate of my pixel of consideration i.e. `add1(i,j)`. now I want to display the connected component of which this pixel is part of. I have tried it with the `regionprop` using `'PixelIdxList'` and `'PixelList'` unsuccesfully.
Can someone help please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your question with a sample image, if you can not attach image pls provide a dropbox or google drive link for the image, unless it is difficult to give any suggestions.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7c01qKgITdpU3YyNk53a3JMZjg/view?usp=sharingThe image is marked with the partial red line (just for representation purposes). I want to calculate the distance between red line and the closest connected component. this

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7c01qKgITdpU3YyNk53a3JMZjg/view?usp=sharing  :image marked with red line (for representation) I want to calculate distance between red line (Layer) and closest connected component.display this component.am able to get the pixel coordinates of red marked pixels. I am propagating reversely from this layer column wise and am able to get one pixel coordinate now I want to display this connected component of which this pixel is part. Conclude : My main objective is to display those connected components which are less than 10 pixel close to the layer the red line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, what you want is: given a specific coordinates `(i,j)` what is the label, and mask of the connected component that `(i,j)` is part of.

```
add = bwlabel( add1 ); %// convert to label mask
lij = add(i,j); %// get the label to which i,j belongs to
figure;
imshow( add == lij, [] ); %// select only the relevant label
```

Comment: got an error : Error using figure
Figures cannot be created from non-figure handles.

Error in Manifestated (line 449)
                      figure( imshow( add == lij, [] ) ); %// select only the relevant label
Error might be in my looping code, I am looking for it.will return here soon thank you. Its working a little bit. Appreciate your contribution.thanks.

Comment: Again, it worked,still there is some bug in my loops.not getting desired results,thinking to work with some other approach.However it worked.thanks allot..

Comment: I am currently not able to vote up.I will be back after getting my results.Thank You once again.

Comment: Hello Again. How can we save this specific label in a variable so that it can be used further as an image and can perform image manipulations. I tried it though am not able to access the image pixel. Then I thought to write the image using "imwrite" and then use it but its the last option. There would be some better way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @DrEma you can save the `lij` mask into a variable `mask_ij= (add==lij);` then you can `save( filename, 'mask_ij');` write it to mat-file and load it as you please. If you save a mask to image do NOT use jpeg format - it is a lossy format. Use png format with indexed image.

Answer (score 2):

As much i understand you want this:

```
            clc
            clear all
            close all

            im = imread('labelProb.png');
            im = im2bw(im);

            labelIm = bwlabel(im);
            rg = regionprops(im,'PixelIdxList','Centroid');

            figure,imshow(labelIm,[]),hold on
            for i = 1:length(rg)
                cc = rg(i).Centroid;
                text(cc(1),cc(2),['label: ',num2str(i)],'Color','b','FontSize',9)
            end
            f = getframe();
            lab = frame2im(f);
            hold off

            % suppose you want label number 3 only.

            cc = rg(3).Centroid; % this is your pixel index;
            % Extract label number through this index.
            cc = round(cc);
            labelNumber = labelIm(cc(2),cc(1));

            % create a new blank image.
            blankImage = false(size(im));

            for i = 1:length(rg)
                if i == labelNumber
                    blankImage(rg(i).PixelIdxList) = true;
                end
            end
            figure,imshow(blankImage,[])
```

And result of above execution are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7c01qKgITdpU3YyNk53a3JMZjg/view?usp=sharing  :image marked with red line (for representation) I want to calculate distance between red line (Layer) and closest connected component.display this component.am able to get the pixel coordinates of red marked pixels. I am propagating reversely from this layer column wise and am able to get one pixel coordinate now I want to display this connected component of which this pixel is part. Conclude : My main objective is to display those connected components which are less than 10 pixel close to the layer the red line.

Comment: Seems I might not be able to correctly put my problem

Comment: As you can find the pixels of nearest (i.e. 10 pixels far) from your pixels of interest, you can follow the procedure described in above code. make a label image from attached image, now follow the same procedure as you are following, when you got your first pixel index, find out label number on the same index in the label image, and follow the code(as i have written) for keeping only those labels; index of which you are getting.

Comment: I am not able to get the index. For example say the add=bwlabel(add1); image add1(i,j) is the pixel of interest, then I did rg=regionprop(add,'PixelIdxList');. Now how should I access index and show the corresponding complete connected component.

Comment: hi ema refer the code i have posted in my answer....plz give it some time to understand.

Comment: hello, I have gone through it, I am still working over it with merging some different concept or idea.thank you. I  am working either to change my approach towards my problem or so.I will response.thanks....